# Emacs Modes: "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer"

Tags: emacs, elisp, modal-dialog

Scenario:

- I start to type M-x to type a command
- I switch to another emacs window/buffer because I realise I'm executing the command in the wrong window
- I start to type M-x again to execute the command in the correct window

Result: I get the dreaded "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer"

This happens to me multiple times a day while using emacs, and not just in this scenario.  This behaviour is highly user-hostile (ref. Modes and Pseudo-modes in `The Humane Interface` by Jef Raskin)

Is there a way to customize emacs behaviour so that instead of giving this error, it just cancels the first minibuffer and replaces it with a new one?

Comment: Another way to look at is that it's your workflow above that's broken, not emacs.  G-g out of the minibuffer before changing buffers to set a new region or whatever, rather than trying to recurse (as you're doing)

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you are more user hostile than emacs in this case!  It is up to the app to accomodate the users' workflow, otherwise why implement undo?  And no, this isn't recursion at all.

Comment: While I appreciate that modern design practices avoid modality, emacs was designed in the distant past and has modes aplenty. If the modality of emacs is problematic, I would frankly recommend not using it. Emacs *is* user hostile. Personally, I got over it and learned to use it and found a lot of power available, but that was back when emacs was king of the roost. These days I rarely dip into it.

Comment: If something is broken, it's the tool, not the user (as a 1st approximation). There's a reason why EoghanM is confused.

In this case, because the minibuffer is always visible, it's not related to a buffer in particular, so why should a M-x command stick to the buffer it was started from? Emacs doesn't even indicate to which buffer the command will apply.

Comment: Thanks guys - Godeke could you recommend a better editor in an answer?  Obviously VI is also highly modal.  I did try Archy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archy a few years back but I think it's dead.

Comment: Trey's solution looks workable. Personally I have been using Eclipse's editor or Emacs when off Windows and Visual Studio's built in editor, Ultra Edit or Notepad++ (depending on context) when on Windows.

Comment: FWIW: I use other windows/buffers all the time from the minibuffer, including using the mouse in them. With *no confusion or annoyance*. I don't use the minibuffer just to enter input. I use a powerful minibuffer (Icicles) with key bindings that *do* things. I use commands that allow recursive minibuffers fairly often (but I wouldn't use a rec. minibuffer in the case cited). I use a standalone minibuffer frame ([oneonone.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el)) whose background color changes slightly for each recursive level. And I use `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed this emacs "feature" is aggressive and annoying.
I found this to be the right answer to the problem .Most likely you lost focus of the minibuffer because you switched windows with the mouse and NOT a minibuffer command. So whenever you lose focus using the mouse, the minibuffer will be cleared. Check this post. It works for me and it's way better than recursive minibuffers which will cause a headache

http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2010/04/emacs-tip-36-abort-minibuffer-when.html

Answer (score 9):

You can set the variable `enable-recursive-minibuffers`, which will prevent that error message from coming up.  But it just enables multiple calls to the minibuffer - it doesn't redirect the current minibuffer's command to the new buffer.  You can give this a try, but I think it'll be more confusing because the original action is still pending...

`M-x` is bound to `'execute-extended-command`, and re-hosting (changing the original buffer) for that command is kind of like programming with continuation.  i.e. you call a subroutine from location X, but instead of returning to X when done, you return to Y.  I personally think it'd open up more confusion than it'd solve.  But I understand the frustration (and know others who have the same frustration).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if there is such a customization, but the way I avoid this is hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to cancel the command I was in the middle of writing in the minibuffer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of ctrl-g and use it a lot, but I can't seem to incorporate it into my workflow in this scenario - I think the reason is that I don't want to cancel the command, just redirect it to another window.

Answer (score 4):

Since my first answer doesn't directly give you what you want, I thought I'd come up with a real solution.  This is what I have:

```
(defvar my-execute-extended-command-source-buffer nil
  "var holding the buffer to which the extended-execute-command should apply")
(defvar in-my-execute-extended-command nil
  "internal use - indicates whether we're in a 'recursive edit' of sorts")
(defun my-execute-extended-command (command)
  "home-grown version of execute-extended-command that supports re-hosting the buffer"
  (interactive (list (if in-my-execute-extended-command
                   nil
                 (let ((in-my-execute-extended-command t))
                   (setq my-execute-extended-command-source-buffer (current-buffer))
                   (completing-read "My-x " obarray 'commandp t nil 'extended-command-history nil nil)))))
  (if in-my-execute-extended-command
      (progn (setq my-execute-extended-command-source-buffer (current-buffer))
             (select-window (minibuffer-window)))
    (switch-to-buffer my-execute-extended-command-source-buffer)
    (call-interactively (symbol-function (intern command)))))
```

I've tested it this way.  I bound it to a key (`F10` in my case b/c I didn't want to lose `M-x`).  Then, with two windows open, each showing a different buffer (say A and B):

1. From window showing buffer A: `F10 isearch-for`
2. Switch from minibuffer to window showing A: `C-x o`
3. Switch from window showing A to that showing B: `C-x o`
4. "re-host" the command from buffer B: `F10`
5. Now back in the minibuffer, finish the command `ward RET`

When I started typing a search term, the search applied to buffer B.

This only replaces the `M-x` functionality, not the commands invoked from `M-x`.  Also, this version does not support the prefix argument.

Hopefully this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Trey, I'll bind this to M-x and see how I get on.  I see one immediate problem that the after execution of the command at step 5, buffer A is replaced by buffer B (so now I have two B buffers in both windows).  Maybe that's something quirky with my setup - you've given me enough to continue to develop an answer that suits me.

Comment: The buffer changing happens with me as well, I don't know of a way to fix that.  I think the handling of `interactive` forces the command to originate from the window from which you start.  But that's a guess.  I wasn't able to solve that problem with `'save-window-excursion` (which was the first thing that came to mind).

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
;; automatically cancel the minibuffer when you switch to it, to avoid
;; "attempted to use minibuffer" error.
;; cy was here

(provide 'cancel-minibuffer)

(defun cancel-minibuffer-first (sub-read &rest args)
    (let ((active (active-minibuffer-window)))
        (if active
                (progn
                    ;; we have to trampoline, since we're IN the minibuffer right now.
                    (apply 'run-at-time 0 nil sub-read args)
                    (abort-recursive-edit))
            (apply sub-read args))))

(advice-add 'read-from-minibuffer :around #'cancel-minibuffer-first)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can anyone improve on the following?

I've given up and just want to set \C-w to cancel any previous minibuffer before opening a new one (like doing \C-g\C-w)

So far thanks to Trey I've got:

```
(defun cancel-completing-read ()
  (if (> (minibuffer-depth) 0) (exit-minibuffer))
   (completing-read "My-x " obarray 'commandp t nil 'extended-command-history nil nil))

(defun cancel-and-execute-command (command)
  (interactive (list (cancel-completing-read)))
  (call-interactively (symbol-function (intern command))))

(global-set-key "\M-x" 'cancel-and-execute-command)
```

What command should I use in the place of `exit-minibuffer` above?

I've tried

```
keyboard-escape-quit
exit-minibuffer
keyboard-quit
```